# Matlab FFT - Scaling y-axis

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

As a data basis, I have measured data the volts were recorded.
Matlab will now be used to perform an FFT.
I have the following questions:
- What unit do I have on the ordinate axis after the FFT? Also volts?
- How is scaled correctly? By hiding the negative frequencies (Nyquist), I would actually have to double the amplitude, right?
- Do I have to multiply all values of the FFT again with 20 * log10 (FFT) to represent the ordinate in db?

Thank you so much for your support!
Frank

Matlab example:

```
load('TimeDomain.mat')%loading of the time domain signal
L=2500; %length of the signal
Fs=500000;%sampling frequency
N=2^nextpow2(L);%scale factor
t=(0:L-1)*10^-3;%time domain array
f=linspace(0,Fs/2,length(t));%frequency domain array 

FFT=abs(fft(Timedomain,N));   
figure(1)
plot(f,FFT(1:2500))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, after the FFT, the unit of the ordinate axis will still be volts.
You can scale it by dividing by the number of samples of your signal, then you can indeed multiplying by two (except the first and last elements that represents respectively the frequency `0` and `Fs/2`) if you want to plot all the spectrum in the positive side.

Then if you want to plot in dB, you can use the function [`mag2db`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/mag2db.html) which applies the formula that you said.

I found some weirdnesses in your code, so I suggest some fixes. My `Timedomain`  signal is a 100 kHz sine at 1 V.

```
Fs = 500000;                    % sampling frequency
L = 2500;                       % length of the signal
t = (0:L-1)/Fs;                 % time domain array
f = linspace(0, Fs/2, L/2+1);   % frequency domain array

Timedomain = cos(2*pi*100000*t); % Input signal

FFT = abs(fft(Timedomain)/L);
FFT(2:L/2) = 2*FFT(2:L/2);

%% Plots
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(f, FFT(1:L/2+1)); xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Tension (V)');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(f, mag2db(FFT(1:L/2+1))); xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Tension (dBV)');
```

This returns:

[image: scaling_y]

Comment: Octave on Debian requires the `control` package to get `mag2db`. It can be installed with `apt-get install octave-control`. In order to use it, it has to be loaded with `pkg load control`.